# How do I return a dataframe from a function within a function?

Tags: python, dataframe, function, return

I'm trying to write a function within a function; the outer function asks the user what dataset they wish to consolidate and the inner function consolidates datasets enclosed in a particular list. The list chosen is determined by the user's input.

```
def ConsolidateData():

    def AppendData(dataList):
        main_df = pd.read_excel(dataList[0])
        for f in dataList[1:]:
            df = pd.read_excel(f)
            main_df.append(df)
        return main_df

    consolInput = input('What dataset do you want to consolidate?: ')
    if 'Purchase Invoice' in consolInput:
        return AppendData(PI_data)
    else:
        print("Nada")
```

AppendData takes the first filename in a list, creates a dataframe and then appends the remaining files in the list to the created dataframe.

PI_data is one of the lists containing the names of 3 or 4 files. I plan to have other lists of filenames as well and have those be part of the 'if' statements that come after the consolInput code.

When I run call the outer function and try to print the main_df after the function is run, I get an 'Undefined name main_df' error.

I've tried placing the AppendData function outside the ConsolidateData function, defining it before and calling it within the ConsolidateData function, but that hasn't worked either.

I'm aware this is an issue of scope, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong/how to solve the issue. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There's no real reason to define `AppendData` inside `ConsolidateData` like this.

Comment: `main_df` only exists (by that name) inside the context of `AppendData()` however if you wanted to "print" it then it is also the value returned by a potential path in `ConsolidateData()`. So what if you try `print(ConsolidateData())`

Comment: Unless you declare `global main_df` in the function, the variable isn't visible outside the function.

Comment: Why do you need to access `main_df` in the first place? The function returns the value, so just assign the return value to a variable and print that.